# Is "Bananas grow in a tropical climate" grammatically correct?

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, zero-article, generic-noun-phrases

I'm trying to learn grammar from an IETLS book, In one of the fill in the blank type question, there is one question such as :

> Bananas grow in _______.

The answers page says that the correct answer is ***Bananas grow in tropical climates***. The word **a** is incorrect before a plural noun.

But what I'm wondering about is, why did they choose the word *climates*? Can I use *climate* instead and use an '**a**' in front of the **tropical**?  Or is **tropical** always used together with the word **climates**?

**EDIT** Maybe I should give more context to the question. This is an example question which required the reader to correct the wrong sample provided. The provided answer is Bananas grow in 'in a tropical climates', and the answer page say the correct answer is:

> Bananas grow in tropical climates. It isn't necessary to repeat the word *in*. The word *a* is incorrect before a plural noun. The word tropical is misspelled.

What makes me wonder is why did they choose climates? Isn't *a tropical climate* also right?

Comment: So... We're both options and you are confused about why one is better than the other or are you asking why your suggestion wasn't included?

Comment: You can say "a tropical climate", it just doesn't make sense here. It would be fine to say something like "This banana was grown in a tropical climate."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is legitimate and grammatical to say

> Bananas grow in a tropical climate.

Consider

> Bananas grow in a tropical climate as opposed to a desert climate.

A sentence with an analogous structure is

> Struggling teens grow better in a protected environment.

Comment: I agree with this. The answer key provides **a** correction to the sentence, not the **only** possible correction to the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

"Bananas grow in a tropical climate." is also correct.

It seems to answer the question, "What types of things grow in a tropical climate?"

Whereas "Bananas grow in tropical climates." seems to answer the question "Where will bananas grow?"

Really it's a poorly written exam question.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, there are many types of tropical climates. Yes, a tropical climate cannot be anything else. However, it varies geographically. We have a Sub-continental tropical climate (South-east Asia), or the South American Tropical climate, or the Caribbean tropical climate (just a few among many [more](http://www.hobotraveler.com/tropical/list-of-tropical-countries.php)). Bananas can grow in any of these places (if not, more). Maybe that's why 'a tropical climate' is not used.

Answer (score 1):

As the word "climate" in your example means

> A region with a particular climate

it is often used in the plural

> Because chili peppers thrive in very warm, hot climates, equatorial regions seem to have the heaviest concentration of pungent cuisine.
>   He had grown up in a hot climate.

You can use a +adjective +climate as well.
Oxforddictionaries.com.

Answer (score 1):

Having read the first four answers, I'll try to describe my understanding of this issue (I'm not a native speaker of English, and Russians tend to make many article usage errors, that's why this question interested me).

---

Imagine that you have opened a plant encyclopedia at a random page. At the top of the page, you see "Banana": the title of a long article. Then you ask your friend to read a random sentence from that article. He reads:

> Bananas grow in tropical climates.

Can you guess from what part of the article this sentence is? It is most likely from the very start of the article. It's part of the basic description of bananas.

To understand fully the meaning of this sentence, you don't need to ask your friend to read a sentence preceding it, or a sentence following it. It's a very "self-contained" sentence. It conveys a generic fact.

We have a class of fruit called "bananas". Not some specific bananas, but generic bananas; an undifferentiated whole called "bananas". We have a class of climates called "tropical climates". Not some specific climates but just "tropical climates" as an undifferentiated whole.

---

Next, you ask your friend to read another random sentence. He reads:

> Bananas grow in **a** tropical climate.

Now it's more likely that this sentence is not from the introductory part of the article. You feel that in order to understand the meaning of this sentence, you'd need to ask your friend to read the preceding sentence, and probably the following sentence.

He reads the sentences surrounding this sentence, and it becomes clearer:

> [...] Studies have shown, however, that this technique works best when the fruit grows well in **a subtropical climate**. Bananas grow in **a tropical climate**. Not in any other. Our geneticists will need an additional decade to adapt this technique", said Dr. Moghaddam.

This sentence is not so "self-contained". You needed to read additional sentences to work out its meaning. There is a contrast between **a subtropical climate** and **a tropical climate**. Furthermore, it's a quote from speech, and sentences are 'broken apart'. Had it been a written communication, Dr. Moghaddam would've wrote:

> Bananas will grow in a tropical climate, but not in any other.

Thus, the sentence with **a tropical climate** does not work well as a standalone sentence relaying some generic fact. This is even more evident in Ed Rutmayer's answer, where the sentence serves as a reply to a question:

> -"What types of things grow in a tropical climate?"
>   -"Bananas"
>   -"What?"
>   -"*Bananas* grow in a tropical climate". (the answering person here stresses the word *bananas* using intonation ([prosody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_(linguistics))))

We can construe another question:

> -"What bananas do a tropical climate?"
>   -"Bananas *grow* in a tropical climate." (Here, the stress in speech falls on *grow*)

Thus, while the sentence with **a tropical climate** is not ungrammatical, it does not fit well as a "self-contained" sentence in the way the sentence with **tropical climates** does. The sentence with **tropical climates** is "more generic".

---

Why is it so? In my opinion, the key linguistic term to google about is "generic noun phrase". From the linguistic standpoint, we can form a generic noun phrase in several ways:

> **The tropical climate** is the best climate for these plants. (Not some specific climate: a generic "tropical climate"; we use the definite article **the**)
>   **A tropical climate** is better than an arctic climate. (Not some specific tropical climate: any representative member of the class 'tropical climate'; we use the indefinite article **a**)
>   **Tropical climates** have been studied a lot over the last 100 years.

The problem is that there are slight differences in meaning between a 'indefinite generic' noun phrase, a 'definite generic' one, and a 'plural generic'. According to Quirk et al. (1985),

> - The generic use of **a** picks out ANY REPRESENTATIVE MEMBER OF THE CLASS.  (from Unit 5.53)
> - The generic use of **the zero article** with both plural nouns and noncount nouns 
>     identifies the class considered as an UNDIFFERENTIATED WHOLE. (from Unit 5.54)
> - **The** is rather limited in its generic function. With singular heads, it is often formal or literary in tone, indicating THE CLASS AS REPRESENTED BY ITS 
>     TYPICAL SPECIMEN (from Unit 5.55)

Furthermore, the authors of the book write (Unit 5.52) that then the noun phrase is not the subject in a clause, it could lose its generic function. They provide an example in which the 'definite generic' retains its generic nature, the 'plural generic' is somewhat changed in meaning, and the 'indefinite generic' loses its generic function.

> Nora has been studying **the** medieval history play. ("mystery plays as a genre"; generic meaning)
>   Nora has been studying **a** medieval history play. (one specific play; the meaning is non-generic)
>   Nora has been studying medieval history plays. ("most likely refers to a subset of plays")

Furthermore, other parts of the sentence, such as verbs, play a role in determining whether a noun phrase is generic and what shades of 'generic meaning' it has. There's a 55-page PDF titled "[Generic Noun Phrases](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/dissertation/IV-GenericNPs.pdf)" written by [Jown Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) that shows just how complex this issue is.

Comment: I. Demand. A. TL;DR!

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. - if there are no downvotes for some time, I'll write one. (0:

Comment: I won't downvote this, but it seems like you're overanalyzing it. I have no problem with _Bananas grow in a warm climate_ **anywhere** in an article; that's just a normal way of using the word _climate_. Other examples (from books): _Most viniferas grow best in a Mediterranean-type of climate with long, relatively dry summers and mild winters; “Cool-season” cereals (wheat, rye, barley, and oats) grow best in a moderate climate; These trees grow in a temperate climate; Several orchids which usually grow in a warmer climate will also thrive in the warmer parts of the intermediate orchid house._

Comment: @J.R. - thanks for the comment! What if we delete **best** and **most**? "Viniferas grow in a Mediterranean-type of climate." Would this work as a standalone generic sentence? This was my point. Maybe I failed to get it across. Or maybe I was wrong, then I'll ditch the answer.

Comment: My feeling is that **in tropical climates** creates the "most generic" version of this sentence. "Viniferas grow in **a** mild climate". Hmm.. Is this "mild climate" generic? Or could it be a specific climate? Or maybe there's some missing information, which we might get from neighboring sentences. This sentence carries an air of "some information missing" for me.

Comment: A mild climate is a mild climate; I don't read too much into the indefinite article there. _Snowmen don't like a tropical climate_ doesn't seem any more unusual than, say, _Yesterday was a rainy day_. But I wouldn't delete this answer. I may not agree with it 100%, but there are some interesting kernels to think about.

Comment: "A snowman is a antropomorphic figure made of snow. Snowmen are widespread **in a cold climate**. There are different methods for making a snowman.." -- Would this be a nice start for an encyclopedia article?

Comment: "A snowman is..." makes a better start to an entry than "The snowman is..." (because indef generics work great as definitional statements). But "The snowman is..." would not be *ungrammatical.* It's also true that "Snowmen are widespread in a cold climate" probably works better with a plural generic NP: in cold climates. But the indef generic NP is **not** ungrammatical. At worst, it is unfortunate. So your remark about the OP's sentence *not being ungrammatical, per se* is misplaced. Then the third sentence, "there are different methods..." is fine, for the same reason the first one is.

Comment: Now, there are some contexts in which an indefinite generic NP works as a so-called "stand alone" sentence or so-called "self-contained" sentence, where the def generic would be ungrammaticalish. Vlad says to his wife Rasa: "I have an idea: how about we buy young Boris **a laptop** for Christmas." Vlad says this over breakfast in July and no one has been talking about Christmas presents or any kind of presents, and no one has been talking about Boris, and no one has been talking about laptops or anything of the sort. It's straight out of the blue. NB also that the indef NP is not the subject.

Comment: @NES  "So your remark about the OP's sentence not being ungrammatical, per se is misplaced." - thank you, fixed it.

Comment: @NES & CopperK - My sentence was meant to be an offshoot from the Christmas special _Frosty the Snowman_, when Frosty (afraid of melting) says, "Snowmen don't like red thermometers."

Comment: I think this is nearly correct. This is my understanding: "bananas grow in tropical climates". This is a fact about our bananas and tropical climates on planet earth, in reality. "bananas grow in a tropical climate" this is a fact about tropical climates in the abstract. It's somewhat hypothetical. The latter sentence pairs well with modals like "can" and "will".

Comment: You took out "per se." But the rest of your statemen: is off the mark *...it does not fit well as a "self-contained" sentence in the way the sentence with tropical climates does. The sentence with tropical climates is "more generic".* You have used two phrases here in quotes that are not technical terms and are not realities. There is not "more generic", there is just generic. And I've no idea what a "self-contained" sentence is. I know what you are trying to argue, but I don't agree. I have already shown one context in which a indef generic NP is grealy preferred to a definite generic NP.

Comment: The OP's test has a sentence to correct: "Bananas grow in in a tropical climates" and there were three mistakes in it: *two ins*, *a* before *climates* and, per the OP, *tropics* was misspelled. I doubt the test asked the user anything about which context would the resulting sentence work best in. So, I honestly do not know what you are doing here with this answer except thinking aloud. So what if one type of generic NP answers one question better and another type answers another better. The test asked about errors in a specific sentence; the test was not about what makes the best generic NP.

Comment: @NES - The OP: "Isn't *a tropical climate* also right?". I explained why, while being grammatical, this is not suited well for their particular context (a textbook problem). "Self contained" = requiring no additional information. As Quirk et al. write, generic noun phrases have different shades of meaning. Thus, the sentence with "tropical climates" could be described as "more generic". I do not feel myself obligated to always use technical terms. I feel that my answer contributed to the thread, and I've no prejudice against "thinking aloud". If I strayed too much.. not a big deal.

Comment: -1 because of the points I have raised.

Comment: Consider *Fred likes to drive **a sports car** as often as he gets the chance* which is sentence (30) in Chapter IV of Lawler's dissertation.  Compare with (54) *Fred likes to drive **sports cars**...* but the ungrammatical (per Lawler, p 114) *Fred likes to drive **the sports car**...* I guess a particular person can't drive the prototypical sport car.

Comment: @GoDucks - thank you, I'll revisit John Lawler's work! Should it disprove my answer?